# How to post a TrieField field using SolrJ?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I've been searching for how to pull this off everywhere but seems like nobody has been able to solve this.

So my problem is that I want to update a TrieField field of a document I have indexed in Solr and I don't have a clue of how to do that.

Has anybody done this or how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Federico

Comment: There's *nothing* different when posting to a `Trie*Field` compared to any other field. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick reply! I understand that a TrieField is a range field, so I'm not sure how to submit a range let's say "from 1 to 10"

Comment: you don't post ranges, you post a value. This value can then be used to perform a range query, e.g., `q=tint:[start TO end]`

Comment: You can *NOT* update any fields of a document that you have already indexed. You can only *REPLACE* a document with one that has updated field content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a field like below

```
<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieField" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

You can post to it using the regular approach

```
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);

SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("tint", 1);

server.add(document);
server.commit();
```

Comment: I get it now. I was expecting something that looked like this:
<doc>
   ...
   <trie field>
      <val=[1 TO 10]>
      <val=[11 TO 20]>
   </trie field>
   ....
</doc>
and could perform range queries on that. which is better than having a multivalued field with all the numbers that those ranges cover.